# Upgrade SQLite DataBase Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to upgrade database, but just can not get it to work. I have looked at other question and tried different thing but did not managet to get it to work. Can someone please look at the code and help me.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.ribicinc.pogodi/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "baza.db";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    /**
     *
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);
//        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 4.2){
  //          DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
  //      } else {
   //         DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
   //     }
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    /**
     *
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){

        }else{

            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }


    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vprasanja");
        onCreate(db);
    }


}
```

**UPDATE**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.util.Log;


public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.ribicinc.pogodi/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "baza.db";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;

    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 8;

    /**
     *
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
//        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 4.2){
  //          DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
  //      } else {
   //         DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
   //     }
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    /**
     *
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){

        }else{

            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }


    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE vprasanja");
        //db.execSQL("create table TEXT not null");

         String sql = "CREATE TABLE dummy (" +
                 "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                 "name TEXT, " +
                 "disc TEXT, " +
                 "photo TEXT, " +
                 "prep TEXT, " +
                 "thumb TEXT, " +
                 "ingre TEXT, " +
                 "howto TEXT, " +
                 "info TEXT, " +
                 "snackId INTEGER)";
         db.execSQL(sql);


    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //if (oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2){
        //  Log.d(TAG, String.format("Upgrade DB:(%d -> %d)", oldVersion, newVersion));
        //}

        //switch(newVersion) {
       // default:
         //       throw new IllegalStateException("onUpgrade() with unknown newVersion" + newVersion);
        //}
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vprasanja");
        onCreate(db);
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you change `the Version of your app`??

Comment: Also check   `if (oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2)` in `onUpgrade(.....)`

Comment: @MD I tried, don't get anything. .. if (oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2){
      Log.d(TAG, String.format("Upgrade DB:(%d -> %d)", oldVersion, newVersion));
     }

Comment: @ribicincc Please try my solution. It will definitely help. Just remember to update `DATABASE_VERSION` to something bigger than 2.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make `onUpgrade()` method work you need to increase `DATABASE_VERSION`number with each upgrade. For instance:

`private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
...`

and replace this:

```
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);
```

with this:

```
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION );
```

so that your database is aware of upgrade.

**UPDATE**

It seems that you do not have any code in your `onCreate(db)`. Make sure you add there a code responsible for creating your database.

Comment: @ribicincc Have you updated also a call to super constructor? That's crucial.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: replace this:
    `super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);`
with this:
    `super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION );`

Comment: @ribicincc You need code in your `onCreate(db)` that will in fact create your database.

Comment: But I dont need to create a database if I already have database.

Comment: @ribicincc So what exactly doesn't work? Isn't `onUpgrade()` executed?
If you increase `DATABASE_VERSION` and pass it to super constructor it should be enough for `onUpgrade()` to be called.

Comment: That's the thing, onUpgrade() is not called.

Comment: @ribicincc add `super.onCreate(db)` to your `onCreate(db)` method. This connected with other necessary changes I mentioned will help. The thing is you need to have a database created in `onCreate(db)` so that system knows there is one and can get its number and compare with new `DATABASE_VERSION`.

Comment: When I do that I get this error: Cannot directly invoke the abstract method onCreate(SQLiteDatabase) for the type SQLiteOpenHelper DataBaseHelper.java /Pogodi/src/com/ribicinc/pogodi line 146 Java Problem

Comment: @ribicincc so instead of `super.onCreate(db)` create there small `db.execSQL()` where you create some dummy table.

Comment: Still it doesnt work, still the old database is used.

Comment: @ribicincc Can you post your updated code? in `update` section?

Comment: @ribicincc Is `onUpgrade()` called now?

Comment: No, still is not called. I just cant figure it out what is wrong. You have update above.

Comment: @ribicincc uninstall your app and install again. It will work

Comment: Yeah, but I can't say to all my users on Google Play that they need to delete app and reinstall it :)

Comment: @ribicincc In that case you need to invoke upgrade code manually in your `DatabaseHelper()` constructor. Just make sure you are doing it only for specific update: `if(DATABASE_VERSION == 2){ onUpgradeCode};`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `onCreate(db)`, but your `onCreate()` method is empty. Be sure to call `super.onCreate(db)` and to execute a create statement with `db.execSQL()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onCreate(db);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_STATEMENT);
}
```